# How to use a session variable in shopping cart

Tags: c#, sql-server

I've been trying with no success to create a shopping cart in c# asp.net and SQL server.

I was able to retrieve the products from Database and to create a detail view for each product as well.

Right now I need to create the button "add to cart", I know that I have to create a session variable with an array to save the products information and then show it in the cart but I don't know how.

This is my code in productsDetail.cs:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        SqlConnection connexionBD = new SqlConnection(this.data_un_jouet.ConnectionString);

        SqlCommand commandeJouets = null;

        SqlDataReader lecteurJouets = null;

        try
        {
            connexionBD.Open();

            String id = Request.QueryString["no"];

            Session["product"] = id;

            string myQuery = data_un_jouet.SelectCommand;

            commandeJouets = new SqlCommand(myQuery, connexionBD);

            commandeJouets.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.Int).Value = Convert.ToInt32(id);

            lecteurJouets = commandeJouets.ExecuteReader();

            TableRow uneLigne;
            TableCell uneCellule;

            while (lecteurJouets.Read())
            {
                uneLigne = new TableRow();
                string myID = Convert.ToString(lecteurJouets["id"]);

                uneCellule = new TableCell();
                uneCellule.Text = Convert.ToString(lecteurJouets["name"]);
                uneLigne.Cells.Add(uneCellule);                    

                uneCellule = new TableCell();
                uneCellule.Text = "<img src=" + lecteurJouets["image"].ToString() + "/>";
                uneLigne.Cells.Add(uneCellule);

                uneCellule = new TableCell();
                uneCellule.Text = Convert.ToString(lecteurJouets["description"]);
                uneLigne.Cells.Add(uneCellule);

                uneCellule = new TableCell();
                uneCellule.Text = Convert.ToString(lecteurJouets["price"]);
                uneLigne.Cells.Add(uneCellule);

                uneCellule = new TableCell();
                uneCellule.Text = "<a href=\"cart.aspx?no=" + myID + "\" />Add to cart</a>";
                uneLigne.Cells.Add(uneCellule);

                this.un_jouet.Rows.Add(uneLigne);
            }

            lecteurJouets.Close();
            commandeJouets.Dispose();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            msgErreur.Text = "Erreur de connexion ! " + ex.Message;
        }
        finally
        {
            connexionBD.Close();
        }
```

I know most of the code is in french, I've tried to translate some of it.

This code works just fine, the problem is that I don't know what to do when the "Add to cart button" is clicked.

I've created a session variable but it only contains the product ID.

Thank you very much for your help,

Answer (score 0):

Like you said you need to assign an array to the session. Better yet, use a List since you don't have a fixed number of items. Let's say that we store the IDs of the items in the shopping cart, and that those IDs are ints. So first we need to instantiate the List. There are many places where you can do this, but for now the Page_Load event is fine.

```
If (Session["ShoppingCart"] == null)
{
    Session["ShoppingCart"] = new List<int>();
}
```

We first check to see if we've already assigned the session variable, and if not we do so.

Then when the customer adds an item to the shopping cart (say presses a button), you need to add this to the code handling that event:

```
var products = (List<int>)Session["ShoppingCart"];
products.Add(newProductId);
```

What I haven't done here (and you should) is to check in the session variable actually has a List to avoid errors. Remember that sessions are not strongly typed.

For better and cleaner code, you should encapsulate the session inside it's own get/set property.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help @System Down 
I've declare the products list on the page load of details.cs
I get this error when running the program: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." It comes from the line where I add my Id's to the list: "products.Add(myID);"
I've added the condition to check if the session exists in cart.cs I'm guessing that I need to loop the list to retrieve the products but I have no Idea how to, I know it's a lot to ask but any help would be wonderful to me.